# переключение объектов в массиве

Tags: c#, unity3d

у меня есть это

```
public GameObject[] dialog_Now;
```

и туда занесено энное количество объектов .
есть ли способ как отображать эти объекты один за другим ?

типа : чтобы был активен только 1 элемент массива ,а все были не видны .

Comment: Берёте элемент по индексу в массиве и делаете его активным, остальные в в цикле придётся делать неактивными. Либо чуть проще: берём элемент по индексу и его индекс кладём  в переменную `activeDialogIndex`. Потом если надо его выключить а другой включить - по `activeDialogIndex` отключаем предыдущий и делаем опять действия для включения, как выше

Answer (score 1):

```
private void Start () {    
    SetActiveElement(dialog_Now, 0);
}

private void SetActiveElement (GameObject[] array, int index) {
    if (array != null && index >= 0 && index < array.Length)
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            array[i].SetActive(i == index);
}
```

Учи основы C#.